# Spring MVC getting HTTP 500 instead of HTTP 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am getting the following error when trying to access an inexistent resource.

*HTTP Status 500* - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "pages/inexistentResource", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

I want to get an HTTP Status 404 in these cases so my web-xml can redirect the user to a proper not found page in my application. It seems my template engine is being a little too trigger-happy and being called on inexistent resources.

Here is my configuration:

```
public class WebConfigSupport extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;


    /**
     * Builds a template resolver, the one who translates template names into template objects.
     */
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver defaultTemplateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        //resolver.setTemplateMode("XHTML");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }

    /**
     * Builds the template engine for Spring MVC.
     */
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        Set<IDialect> dialects = Sets.newHashSet();
        dialects.add(new SpringSecurityDialect());

        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(defaultTemplateResolver());
        engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
        engine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);
        return engine;
    }

    /**
     * Builds the thymeleaf view resolver.
     */
    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return resolver;
    }
    ...
}
```

My web.xml:

```
  ...
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/portal/errors/404</location>
  </error-page>
  ...
```

I am not a spring pro so I am kind lost in what I am doing wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The 500 seems appropriate to me. **You**'re telling your app to resolve `pages/inexistentResource` as a view. If that view doesn't exist, it's a problem of your server, not of the client.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Like I said I am not a spring pro, what I want is to show a proper error message in those cases.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: why is the server trying to resolve the static resource `pages/inexistentResource` if it doesn't exist? Instead of returning 404s, figure out why you are returning that view name. If it should be there, add it. If it shouldn't be there, don't return that view name, return an appropriate one.

Comment: Can you post to us your Webapp folder structure?

Comment: anyone know how to handler this thymeleaf exception to 404 error ,not 500 returned in our global project .

Answer (score 0):

Put all your html or jsp files, In your case, you are mentioned .html extension.

Hope so, it looks like this, `WEB-INF/folderName/.html files`

In the resolver.setPrefix add like this, according to your html folderName

```
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
```

Comment: How could this help? Won't moving the files just make it search for this resource in another place and still fail to get it in the same manner?